# Error Cache cannot write able in Cakephp version 2.7

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I got a problem with cache in Cakephp version 2.7. the message below happen while I've tried to upload it to the real server.

```
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /var/www/html/equalwedding/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 328 Warning: /var/www/html/equalwedding/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/html/equalwedding/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 385 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine "_cake_core_" is not properly configured. Ensure required extensions are installed, and credentials/permissions are correct' in /var/www/html/equalwedding/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:186 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/equalwedding/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1 /var/www/html/equalwedding/app/Config/core.php(374): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2 /var/www/html/equalwedding/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/var/www/html/e...') #3 /var/www/html/equalwedding/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(175): Configure::bootstrap(true) #4 /var/www/html/equalwedding/app/webroot/index.php(104): include('/var/www/html/e...') #5 /var/www/html/equalwedding/index.php(41): require('/var/www/html/e...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/equalwedding/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 186
```

I have to tried to set the permission to folder cache to 777 but there still show me the error.

How could I solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you google the error and try different suggestions? What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: I've tried to open the permission and set the folder cache to 777 but there still show the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check that  app/tmp/cache/models and app/tmp/cache/persistent exists and they are writable.

If it still persists try to clean your old cache and check it back again.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I have both of them but the permission is not writable. So I have just change the permission to the folder and It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have Faced this error. i checked my app location is exists this  cache file.

its not in their.

```
[08-Oct-2018 05:44:32 GMT] PHP Warning:  C:\wamp64\www\app\admin\tmp\cache\persistent\ is not writable in C:\wamp64\www\app\lib\Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine.php on line 385
```

Then I create the "persistent" file in the app/admin/tmp/cache/persistent. Its worked fine.